# how to sove redux toolkit "circular reference" problem

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I have this slice

logout.js

```
import { createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import { logoutUser } from './actions/logoutUserAction';

const initialState = {
  status: null,
};

const logout = createSlice({
  name: 'logout',
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    changeStatus: state => { <===== I want to use this action
      state.status = null;
    },
  },
  extraReducers: {
    [logoutUser.pending]: state => {
      state.status = 'loading';
    },
    [logoutUser.fulfilled]: state => {
      state.status = 'success';
    },
    [logoutUser.rejected]: state => {
      state.status = 'failed';
    },
  },
});

export const { changeStatus } = logout.actions;

export default logout.reducer;
```

logoutuserAction.js

```
import { createAsyncThunk } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import axios from 'axios';
import { changeStatus } from '../logout';

export const logoutUser = createAsyncThunk(
  'logout/logoutUser',
  async (data, { dispatch }) => {
    return axios({
      method: 'get',
      url: '/logout',
      withCredentials: true,
    }).then(res => {
      dispatch(changeStatus()); <=== I use it here
      localStorage.removeItem('isAuthenticated');
      return res.data;
    });
  }
);
```

I was reading about it here
https://redux-toolkit.js.org/usage/usage-guide/#exporting-and-using-slices
but I didn't understand this part:

*If you encounter this, you may need to restructure your code in a way that avoids the circular references. This will usually require extracting shared code to a separate common file that both modules can import and use. In this case, you might define some common action types in a separate file using createAction, import those action creators into each slice file, and handle them using the extraReducers argument.*

What I get:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do that by putting `logoutUser` in the same file, above the `createSlice` call, but... why are you doing that though? A blink of an eye later, `logoutUser.fulfilled` is being dispatched and you can do the same stuff just in that extraReducer..?